# How to pass a Dictionary data from table View to the another View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, segue

I am fetching the contacts of iPhone and make their Dictionary Check my code

```
 -(void) fetchContacts
{

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            //keys with fetching properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
            } else {
                NSString *phone;
                NSString *fullName;
                NSString *firstName;
                NSString *lastName;
                UIImage *profileImage;
                NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray;
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                    // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                    firstName = contact.givenName;
                    lastName = contact.familyName;
                    if (lastName == nil) {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                    }else if (firstName == nil){
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                    }
                    else{
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                    }
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                    if (image != nil) {
                        profileImage = image;
                    }else{
                        profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"acc_sett.png "];
                    }
                    for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                        phone = [label.value stringValue];
                        if ([phone length] > 0) {
                            [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                        }
                    }
                    NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage,@"userImage",phone,@"PhoneNumbers", nil];
                    [_Contacts  addObject:personDict];

                    NSLog(@"%@",phone);
                    NSLog(@"%@",fullName);
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self.contacttableview reloadData];



                });
            }
        }
    }];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_Contacts count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSDictionary* personDict = [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [_contacttableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];





    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];





    }

    cell.imageView.image = [personDict objectForKey:@"userImage"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [personDict objectForKey:@"fullName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [personDict objectForKey:@"phoneNumbers"];
    return cell;
}
```

With the help of this code Dictionary Data is display on the tableview now i want to pass image fullname and phone number of a person on the another view controller on selecting their row.

I have tried many method but not get any result

Comment: You should make proper Class called i.e. MyContact. This data model should be populated with the data you fetch from contact book. That is the first designing issue. And to pass data between classes, there are many methods. You can use properties and set them in segue methods. Or you could use delegate methods etc etc

Answer (score 0):

In YourViewController.h, create a property of Person that you want to pass

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDictionary *person;
```

In TableViewController.m, didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
YourViewController *vc = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
vc.person = [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: How to call the data on ViewController.m of Dctionary

Comment: You can call in viewDidLoad method

Comment: UIImage *userImage = [self.person objectForKey:@"userImage"];
NSString *fullName = [self.person objectForKey:@"fullName"];
NSString *phoneNumbers = [self.person objectForKey:@"phoneNumbers"];

Comment: how can u plz illustrate

Comment: Read the first line of my answer.
After create property in YourViewController.h, and assign its value in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of TableViewController.m, you can access it in YourViewController.m

Comment: i want to pass every person data whose in my contacts if i am select their particular row

Answer (score 0):

First create any NSDictionary object or Your model class object on OtherViewController where you want to navigate then write code like Below,

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OtherViewController *VC = [[OtherViewController alloc] init];
    VC.objContactModel = [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: oak then what i have to do

Comment: Create object on that view controller where you want to navigate then simply write above didSelect Method in your current working controller.

Here "objContactModel" is the object of model class which you have to create.

Comment: If its not working then can u display your did select method here?

Comment: After navigation, You will get data in that object of model class in ViewDidLoad method. You can get by simply using like,  var img = objModel.yourImage..etc

Comment: i have write that code now how to assign data on the label and image view of another view controller

Comment: Access like  UIImage *myImg = [yourModelObject yourImageName](whatever name u have specified in model class) if it works then plz approve my answer...

Comment: First check that your modelObject is nil or not..then u can get your data from your object. if it is null then plz check that in didSelect method that is it assigning with values or not.

Comment: Yess i have check my data model is nil on debugging

Comment: Then plz check that object on didSelect method where you passing that object. and Pass it with some values from indexPath

Comment: How you declare that object on other view controller? plz don't declare using alloc init.ok.

Comment: oh then how i declare

Comment: Simple, make property of that modelClass and use it in OtherViewController.

Comment: Have u define property like,  @property (nonatomic, assign) yourModelClassName *objModel;  In otherVC where u want to get data.

First make it clear that u r passing data on didSelectMethod or not? 
This is simple things for all iOS developer..hope u get it.

Comment: i write like that @property (nonatomic,assign) NSDictionary *person; yes i m passing data on did select method.

Comment: If u r using model class then why r u using NSDictionary?

Comment: U have to make object of your model class

Comment: can you plz tell me in detail

Comment: First, you are using model class right? so while fetching contacts on current controller, you have to add contact one by one in to model class.
Second, you have to create object as i told u earlier and using that object u have to pass data on didSelect method.
Third, u have to access that data on viewDidLoad method.